# beamerarticle and verbatim: how to make fragile?

Tags: verbatim, beamerarticle

Within a beamerarticle style I would like to have use of verbatim. I am using the package 'verbatimbox'. It seems as though together the two packages throw an error (based on the MWE below)

'Paragraph ended before \verbatim@start was complete.'

An output is generated but it does not display the verbatim line breaks nor spacing correctly.

Searching on this site I came across the idea of making the frame fragile, which of course works when you have a frame to make fragile. But I have no frame at this point.

Is there any way to have such a verbatim functionality?

Below is a fully stripped down MWE which is why I have no frames within a beamerarticle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\mode<article>{
text before

\begin{myverbbox}{\mybox}

first line
    second line

    third    line
    
\end{myverbbox}

\mybox

text after
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `verbbox` creation outside of the `\mode` macro.  That is essentially what `verbatimbox` offers: the ability to **create** verbatim material in *safe* locations in your document, and then **use** the material in places were `verbatim` would otherwise be precluded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\mybox}

first line
    second line

    third    line
    
\end{myverbbox}

\mode<article>{
text before

\mybox

text after
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This makes sense. Many thanks!

Comment: @Geoff Just remember that, as a general rule, you can not invoke verbatim creation inside of a macro argument.  The reason is that the argument content is *tokenized* using the current catcodes (at the moment the macro is invoked), whereas `verbatim` needs to change the catcodes of its input stream.